# Using recursion to find sum of all values in first and last rows of 2d array

Tags: c#, recursion, sum

I'm practicing recursion in c# and I have a solution that works, but it uses 3 functions (2 of which are very similar). I'm looking for tips on how to improve this or if I'm even going about it the right way. I'm avoiding for loops and looking to only use recursion to solve this.

```
using System;

namespace RecursionPractice
{
    class Program
    {
        static int sumFirstLastRows(int[,] twoDArr)
        {
            int rowLength = twoDArr.GetLength(1); 

            int sumRow1 = sumFirstRow(twoDArr, rowLength);
            int sumRow2 = sumLastRow(twoDArr, rowLength);

            int sumTotal = sumRow1 + sumRow2;
            return sumTotal;
        }

        static int sumFirstRow(int[,] twoDArr, int N)
        {
            if (N <= 0)
            {
                //base case
                return 0;
            }

            return sumFirstRow(twoDArr, N - 1) + twoDArr[0, N - 1];
        }

        static int sumLastRow(int[,] twoDArr, int N)
        {
            if (N <= 0)
            {
                //base case
                return 0;
            }

            return sumLastRow(twoDArr, N - 1) + twoDArr[1, N - 1];
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] twoD = new int[,] {{ 1, 3, 5 },
                                     {  2, 4, 6  }};

            Console.WriteLine(sumFirstLastRows(twoD));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the 2d array has more than 2 rows, because sumLastRow method returns the sum of the second row.

Comment: Your `sumLastRow()` function seems to sum the values of the second row, not the last.

Comment: This isn't recursive, but it'show I would do it: `var row = twoDArr.GetLongLength(0); var result = twoDArr.Cast<int>().Where((x, n) => n / twoDArr.GetLongLength(1) == row - 1).Sum();`. `row` is your 1-based row number.

Answer (score 1):

[NOTE: for recursive learning only]

As mentioned in comments, your code will calculate first and second rows only, omitted last row if `twoDArr.GetLength(0) > 2`. To `force` this into 1 method recursive call, I devide it into some state (`enum Pointer`) and calculate/skip accordingly.

I believe I am as curious as you so that I did this, please try it:

```
//my enum
public enum Pointer
    {
        Begin,
        First,
        Last,
        Skipped,
        Final
    }
//method
public static int sumFirstLast(int[,] arr, Pointer p = Pointer.Begin, int d1Length = 0, int d2Length = 0, int N = 0)
    {
        var tot = 0;
        switch (p)
        {
            case Pointer.Final:
                return 0;
            case Pointer.Begin:
                return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.First, arr.GetLength(0), arr.GetLength(1));
            case Pointer.First:
                if (d2Length == N)
                {
                    if (arr.GetLength(0) == 2)
                        return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.Last, d1Length, d2Length, 0);
                    return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.Skipped, d1Length, d2Length, 0);
                }
                tot = arr[0, N++];
                return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.First, d1Length, d2Length, N) + tot;
            case Pointer.Skipped:
                return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.Last, d1Length, d2Length, 0);
            case Pointer.Last:
                if (d2Length == N)
                {
                    return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.Final, d1Length, d2Length, 0);
                }
                tot += arr[d1Length-1, N++];
                return sumFirstLast(arr, Pointer.Last, d1Length, d2Length, N) + tot;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
//and..call it
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] twoD = new int[,] {{ 1, 3, 5 }, {0, 0, 0},
                             {  2, 4, 6  }}; //new array added

        Console.WriteLine(sumFirstLast(twoD));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I know that you're trying to use recursion, but this exercise is far simpler with LINQ.

If you start with this:

```
int[,] twoDArr = new int[,]
{
    { 1, 2, 3 },
    { 2, 3, 4 },
    { 3, 4, 5 },
};
```

It's fairly easy to turn that in to a `int[][]` by doing this:

```
int[][] rows =
    twoDArr
        .Cast<int>() // flattens to one dimension
        .Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
        .GroupBy(x => x.index / twoDArr.GetLength(1), x => x.value)
        .Select(x => x.ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

The `.GroupBy` key is `x.index / twoDArr.GetLongLength(1)` so that's an integer starting at zero for each row.

That gives:

[image: rows]

Now you can simply do this:

```
int result = rows.First().Sum() + rows.Last().Sum();
```

The result I get from my sample data is `18` (which is the correct sum of the first and last row).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this has nothing to do with your code. This is simply my version of doing recursive sum for first and last row. I hope it helps.

```
int SumFirstLastRows(int[,] twoD)
{
    // we need some pointer information on when to start and end,
    // let's use column and row number, starting from 0,0
    return SumRecursive(twoD, 0, 0);
}

// this is a recursive method, which goes for each row and column recursively,
// however it only takes the sum of first and last rows' numbers
int SumRecursive(int[,] twoD, int column, int row)
{
    // determine the max row and column, to know when to end
    int maxRows = twoD.GetLength(0);
    int maxColumns= twoD.GetLength(1);

    if (row == maxRows)
    {
        // we are at the end of the rows, end everything
        return 0;
    }
    else if (column == maxColumns)
    {
        // we are at the end of column, switch to the next row instead
        return SumRecursive(twoD, 0, row + 1);
    }
    if ((row== 0 || row == maxRows-1) && column < maxColumns)
    {
        // only for the first or last row: current number + next column sum
        return twoD[row, column] + SumRecursive(twoD, column + 1, row);
    }
    else if(column < maxColumns)
    {
        // not the first or last row, so just skip to the next column
        return SumRecursive(twoD, column + 1, row);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For test:

```
int[,] twod = new int[3,4]
        { {1,2,3,4 },
          {5,6,7,8 },
          {9,10,11,12 }
        };
int recursiveTest = SumFirstLastRows(twod);
int forVerification = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 9 + 10 + 11 + 12;
bool isThisCorrect = recursiveTest == forVerification; // return true!
```